# Get the child type at compile time in C++

Tags: c++, objective-c

I have a reference-counted base class which will be the parent of *most* of my objects. It has its own little reference counted methods. The trouble is, these might be subclassed. In a fashion, I'm trying to implement NSObject, but in C++.

This therefore means there's an 'init' method.

Therefore, the init method should always return the child's class type. Imagine this:

```
class BaseClass{
public:
virtual childclass* init();
}
```

I know in Objective-C this would be quite easy as it returns 'id' and no casting is required. However in C++ there's no such thing as 'id' and therefore I'm hoping there's a macro or something that automatically expands childclass* into the actual child's class. I'm quite new to C++ so I'm not sure how to implement this.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Objective C and it's unclear to me what you want: do you want a function that chooses a derived class of the appropriate type, builds and returns it? If so you can use a `static` factory method in the base class, but it'll need to take some parameters to decide which derived class to use. It should return pointer-to-base. Otherwise what do you mean?

Comment: In C++ world people write code like `std::shared_ptr<BaseClass> base( std::make_shared<ChildClass>( params ) );` for defining ref-counted polymorphic BaseClass pointer that actually points at ChildClass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done via the [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

```
template <class childclass> class BaseClass
{
  public:
    virtual childclass* init();
};

class ChildClass : BaseClass<ChildClass>
{
  public:
    virtual ChildClass* init();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use C++'s constructors which return the proper type. It would work like this:

```
class BaseClass {
    public:
        BaseClass();
        virtual ~BaseClass();
};

class childClass : public BaseClass {
    public:
        childClass();
        virtual ~childClass();
};
```

Then you can simply call `new childClass` and you'll get a pointer to the childClass.